# Repeat the alt text and title text for a series of image field values

Tags: media

I have created a content type for an image gallery, and added an image field with alt text and title tags and gave unlimited upload feature.

If I upload 10 images I want to give the title and alt tags 10 times. Can I bypass each individual image by giving these details one time and applying for all subsequent images?

Is this possible to do via the Drupal admin UI?

Comment: Have you got a custom template ? Are you using an image style ?

Comment: i am using theme seven for Admin UI . I gave the option to enter alt and title while uploading images.The problem is if i am uploading 20 images ,i need to enter it 20 times.if i have the option to give one alt and title for all images it will be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You could just implement a custom template for your field and implement whatever logic you require there.

So, in admin, you could enter the alt and title just for the first image, and then with the template you could apply the alt and title to all the images.

Does that make sense to you ?

Answer (score 0):

I not sure will this help you. You can use node clone module. What you need to do is clone the node and change the picture.
https://www.drupal.org/project/node_clone